# Two SSDs,which are exactly same, but sequential write performance varied widely?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, ssd

I bought two SSDs,which are exactly same, but sequential write performance varied widely? `sdb` is the first SSD, `sdc` is the second SSD, and partitions are same(both `sd*1` and `sd*2`)

[image]

and the `sdb1`'s sequential write is 223MB/s but the `sdc1`'s sequential write is only 161MB/s

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: both are connected to SATAIII ports?

Comment: Try and change the ports over. On my motherboard there are 4 SATA3 ports and 2 of them are from a different chip and are slower.

Comment: swap sata cables and test again?  perhaps a bad cable?

Comment: also, are they at the same firmware revision?

Answer (score 0):

A write may or may not require an erase.